# what is the difference between using useEffect inside a custom hook and a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to know the difference b/w using `useEffect` hook in a component and a custom hook.

For example

If i have a functional component (Component) and directly use `useEffect` hook inside it

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';

function Component(){
   useEffect(()=>{
       //some code                     //callback fires after component renders
   },)

   return (<div>Component</div>)

}
```

if a create a custom hook (useCustomHook)

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
function useCustomHook(){
   useEffect(()=>{
      //some code     //this callback also get fired after component renders
    })
}
```

Now if i use this custom hook inside Component

```
import useCustomHook from 'customhook';
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
function Component(){

   useCustomHook();

    return(<div>Component</div>)

}
```

I want to know

Is the `useEffect` hook related to the `Component`, so that it's callback only run after the `Component` renders, because In using `useCustomHook` it was declared outside of the `Component` i.e it was inside the custom hook, but then also the callback get's called only after the `Component` renders,

So is there any relation b/w `useEffect` and `Component`, So that the callback of `useEffect` get's called only after `Component` renders, no matter wheter the `useEffect` is declared inside or outside of the `Component` i.e (useCustomHook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the custom hook is invoked the logic inside it will not be evaluated and hence regardless of what hook you define inside of it, those are not run at the time of definition

The `useEffect` function inside custom hook will only run when you use it inside a functional component and invoke it. Also note that the behavior of `useEffect` will remain exactly the same as if it were written inside the functional component itself

Comment: You said that,The useEffect function inside custom hook will only run when you use it inside a functional component and invoke it,  so do you mean the useEffect hook or the callback function and secondly  by invoking do you mean useEffect or custom hook

Comment: I mean both, untill you invoke the custom hook inside the functional component or you define useEffect inside a functional component and render it somewhere

Comment: So it means using useEffect inside a custom hook is same as directly using it inside a functional component it will behave same, ie the callback will run on component render

Comment: yes, but it gives an abstraction when you have the same logic in multiple components

Comment: Thnks man could you anwer my another question it will be a great help https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/4845636

Answer (score 0):

Suppose inside the functional component you have written 3 effects. You also have 2 custom hooks that have 1 effect each. So when you use these custom hooks inside your functional component you can imagine that now there are a total of 5 effects inside your functional component who's callback function will be invoked when the condition will meet after the component is being rendered.

Effects defined inside the functional components runs after the component is rendered and the browser in painted. React also guarantees that all the effects will run before the next render. But the order in which effect's callback function will be invoked depends totally on the amount of time taken to execute it.

Here is the link to a code sandBox explaining my point
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-murdock-5ifil?file=/src/useTry.js